# MediatR notification handler dispose behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, mediatr

I'm implementing a .NET 8 worker service with Quartz.NET & MediatR. The flow of which is:

> Gets triggered after certain intervals (defined by cron expression) by
> Quartz.NET job scheduler --> Call an external RESTful API --> Publish
> the API response through MediatR --> *Repeat*

There is a MediatR notification handler, it is supposed to receive the message and store it in AWS DynamoDB.

The code of the handler is roughly:

```
using MediatR;

namespace TestApp;

public class TestNotificationHandler : INotificationHandler<NotificationData>, IDisposable
{
    public async Task Handle(NotificationData notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // save notification to DynamoDB

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       // dispose DynamonDB context
    }
}
```

The issue is:
The Quartz.NET job trigger is finishing execution before the notification could be handled (i.e. saved to DynamoDB) and so the `Dispose()` method is getting invoked.

Is this the correct behaviour? What needs to be changed if I want to make sure the handlers run independently of the Quartz.NET job trigger?

Comment: I'm not into Quartz, but your error sounds like something is calling an async method without awaiting it and then immediately calling dispose. I don't think that such a fundamental error is in the Quartz lib, so probably check your code for a missing await.